# Android Wowza wowz:// streaming url

Tags: android, video-streaming, live-streaming, wowza

I'm trying to connect to wowza server to make stream with my android app.

But it says that there is an error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839207/android-wowza-stream-authmod-adobe).

`wowz://streaming-beta.anssoon`

But the other thing is that it gives me this URL and `wowz` seems strange to me because we are working with `RTSP` protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wowz` protcol is used between a Wowza origin server and Wowza edge server. Even if you are streaming over RTSP, the communication between a Wowza origin and edge server will be over `wowz://`.